# Why some texts and rectangle not showing on pdf after merged using mergePage function of PyPDF2?

Tags: python, pypdf

I want to merge two pdf pages to generate a new page. But it works on some pdf files, it will not show text and rectangle (that I want to add to original pdf page) when I passing specific file.

When I am merging pages with `test11_issued2.pdf`, it works.

But when I am merging pages with `test22_issued2.pdf`, it failed and don't print any error log.

These two pdf are basically same.

PDF files can be found at this link: https://github.com/fangwangme/pdf-exchanger/tree/main/pdfs

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

output = PdfFileWriter()
input1 = PdfFileReader(open("test11.pdf", "rb"))

page = input1.getPage(0)
#watermark = PdfFileReader(open("test11_issued2.pdf", "rb"))
watermark = PdfFileReader(open("test22_issued2.pdf", "rb"))

watermark_page = watermark.getPage(0)

page.mergePage(watermark_page)
output.addPage(page)

outputStream = open("output.pdf", "wb")
output.write(outputStream)
```

The text and rectangle are not showing on PDF reader app, but I can read it from below code.

```py
print(page.extractText())
```

Excepted result should look like as shown in the below picture.

[image: img1]